# Android contact - does it have a unquieid?

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

Android contact - does each contact have a unquieid? How do I get the unquieid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void getContactInfo(Intent intent)
{

   Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
   {           
       String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
       name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

       String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

       if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
           hasPhone = "true";
       else
           hasPhone = "false" ;

       if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
       {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
        {
          phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }
        phones.close();
       }

       // Find Email Addresses
       Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,null, null);
       while (emails.moveToNext()) 
       {
        emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
       }
       emails.close();

    Cursor address = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,
                null, null);
    while (address.moveToNext()) 
    { 
      // These are all private class variables, don't forget to create them.
      poBox      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
      street     = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
      city       = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
      state      = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
      postalCode = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
      country    = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
      type       = address.getString(address.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
    }  //address.moveToNext()   
  }  //while (cursor.moveToNext())        
   cursor.close();
}//getContactInfo
```

Comment: Does the contactId ever change?